# C++ operator<< compile error with gtest AssertionFailure

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, googletest, crtp

**UPDATE:** I have simplified this question's code, and removed the original, more complex code.

Please help me understand what is causing the error I describe below.

I have defined a simple 4xfloat vector type `Vector4f`. For now I have only defined the index operator, however eventually I will define operators for addition, subtraction, etc. I have also defined a stream operator for serialisation of the vector to a stream. Only public methods are used by this operator, so it is not a `friend` of `Vector4f`.

vector.h:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_HPP
#define VECTOR_HPP

namespace vector {

class Vector4f {
public:
  Vector4f(float x0, float x1, float x2, float x3) :
    storage_({x0, x1, x2, x3}) {}

  float & operator[](size_t i) { return storage_[i]; }
  const float & operator[](size_t i) const { return storage_[i]; }

 protected:
  typedef std::vector<float> StorageType;
  StorageType storage_;
};

template <typename StreamType>
StreamType & operator<<(StreamType & s, const Vector4f & v) {
  return s << "[ " << v[0] << ", " << v[1] << ", " << v[2] << ", " << v[3] << " ]";
}

} // namespace vector

#endif // VECTOR_HPP
```

I'm compiling with C++11 (clang). The stream serialisation template seems to work for ostream:

```
std::cout << vector::Vector4f(1,2,3,4) << std::endl;  // compiles
```

Where I run into problems is with GoogleTest's `AssertionFailure` class, that can be used with a stream operator to add information. I'm looking to eventually use a helper function to check that a vector contains the values I expect (without relying on an equality operator that doesn't yet exist). For simplicity, I'm using the assertion directly here:

test_vector.cc:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "vector.h"

class TestVector : public ::testing::Test {};

TEST_F(TestVector, ctor_by_float_parameters) {
  vector::Vector4f v(0.0f, 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f);
  EXPECT_TRUE(::testing::AssertionFailure() << v);
}
```

The compiler fails with this error:

```
In file included from test_vector2.cc:2:
./vector2.h:21:10: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'std::__1::basic_stringstream<char,
      std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type
      'basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >'
  return s << "[ " << v[0] << ", " << v[1] << ", " << v[2] << ", " << v[3] << " ]";
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
googletest/include/gtest/gtest-message.h:131:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'vector::operator<<<std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >'
      requested here
    *ss_ << val;
         ^
googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:306:29: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'testing::Message::operator<<<vector::Vector4f>' requested here
    AppendMessage(Message() << value);
                            ^
test_vector2.cc:10:45: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'testing::AssertionResult::operator<<<vector::Vector4f>' requested here
  EXPECT_TRUE(::testing::AssertionFailure() << v);
```

From what I understand, it is having trouble applying the result of the `operator<<` template for my Vector class to the `operator<<` for the testing::AssertionFailure class. I don't understand why this is causing a problem as it ought to be invoking the AssertionFailure's operator after it has serialised my vector into a stringstream. There's something going on here that I don't yet understand, and I certainly don't understand the error message itself.

Any help appreciated, please.

Comment: This is too much information for me. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RSahu ok, thank you for your advice. I have updated my question with a simpler version that exhibits the same compiler error.

Comment: I don't understand why your `operator<<` function has to be a template and cannot just use class `std::ostream`. That would probably remove the problem all along.

Comment: It seems like it should work. Perhaps someone more knowledgeable than me can help you out.

Comment: @AntonioPérez if I replace `StreamType` with `::std::ostream` (and remove it from the template, and and incorporate @n.m.'s fix too), I get the error: `invalid operands to binary expression` for `std::ostream<char>` and `const char *` on the `s << "[ "` bit. I don't understand why this simple substitution doesn't work, but maybe that's material for a separate question.

Comment: @AntonioPérez the std::basic_stream template exists for a good reason, programmers are supposed to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return s << "[ " << v[0] << ", " << v[1] << ", " << v[2] << ", " << v[3] << " ]";
```

should be

```
s << "[ " << v[0] << ", " << v[1] << ", " << v[2] << ", " << v[3] << " ]";
return s;
```

This is because `operator<<(float)` is a **member function** of `std::basic_ostream`. It returns `std::basic_ostream<...>&`, not the type of the stream you are calling it with. You cannot convert it to `StreamType&`, unless `StreamType` happens to be a `basic_ostream`, which is the case with `std::cout`.

Alternatively, declare your `operator<<` as

```
template <typename VectorType, typename... StreamArgs>
std::basic_ostream<StreamArgs...> &
 operator  <<  (std::basic_ostream<StreamArgs...>& s, 
                const BaseVector<VectorType> & v)
```

Comment: Thank you - the first suggestion resolved the issue for me, however I will also read up on variadic template arguments so I can understand your second suggestion.

Comment: Do you know why replacing `StreamType` with `std::ostream` causes the compiler error I mentioned in one of the comments on my question? Based on what you've explained, I would have expected this to work, as `std::ostream` is a `basic_ostream<char>`.

Comment: @meowsqueak I couldn't reproduce that error. You probably had it incorrect somewhere else. But this solution is not recommended. What if someone uses `std::wostream`, or one with a non-default allocator, or whatever?

Comment: That was my original thinking - keep it templated and then it should work as long as the StreamType has an `operator<<` defined. I'm happy to keep it as-is.